# Resize input to fit its content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do not care for a specific technology, it could be JS, CSS or even some unstandard and evil html attributes. I just want the `input` to get bigger if user types over the right border.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe someone else has a better way, but you could try this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aAueA/1/

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

input.onkeypress = input.onkeydown = function() {
    this.size = ( this.value.length > 10 ) ? this.value.length : 10;
};
```

This sets it at a minimum size of 10 and expands if you go beyond 10 characters.

Probably works best with a fixed width font:

```
input {
    font-family:Courier;
}
```

Comment: More concise version of the function: `this.size = Math.max(this.value.length, 10);`

Answer (score 17):

Let the browser do the calculating of the width by using a `div` with `contenteditable` set to `true`.

```
<div class="pseudo-input" contenteditable="true">Resizes to my content!</div>
```

There should be no issues with browser support http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable

Comment: FYI, this allows unsanitized HTML input, which is dangerous and should generally be avoided

Answer (score 5):

You can also create div element, copy your input style to it and use it's dimensions to resize input. (Chosen multiple uses [this solution](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/coffee/chosen.jquery.coffee#L479-L502)).

```
var input = $('input'),
    dummy = $('<div style="position:absolute; left: -1000%;">').appendTo('body');

['font-size', 'font-style', 'font-weight', 'font-family',
 'line-height', 'text-transform', 'letter-spacing'].forEach(function(index) {
    dummy.css(index, input.css(index));
});

input.on('input', function() {
   dummy.html(this.value);
   input.width(dummy.width());
});
```

UPD: better to use pre instead div to follow spaces size.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It doesn't take into account consecutive whitespace characters, though. I edited your post and added "white-space:pre" to the div dummy. Also, a few pixels extra width might be necessary to avoid that the caret disappears.