# CSS Similar Property to HorizontalAlignment = Stretch of WPF?

Tags: css, wpf

In WPF, when I want to a Label stretch (auto-size) by the text lenght, I can set:

```
label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
```

Is there any similiar function in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements with `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` will expand to fit content. Also floated elements e.g. `float: left`.

Inputs are more tricky. You could use `<span id="input" contenteditable="true">10000</span>` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9EfZ/1) if that is possible with your framework or look at this solution: [Resize input to fit its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663716/resize-input-to-fit-its-content)

Comment: didn't work for me. Do I have to combine with any other property?

Comment: I have this: <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_currentPageNumberPendings" type="text" style="display: inline-block; float: left; width: auto;" value="10000" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$currentPageNumberPendings">

Comment: Inputs are more tricky. You could use `<span id="input" contenteditable="true">10000</span>` http://jsfiddle.net/m9EfZ/1/ if that is possible with your framework or look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663716/resize-input-to-fit-its-content

Comment: Yeah, that's a solution, but I didn't wish to use Javascript to solve this. I knew I could do that :D. Well, if noone says that exists a better solution in CSS, I will accept this as an anwser. Thanks Mathias.