# Cannot read full text in input if it has property onfocus="this.blur()

Tags: javascript, html, text, input, onblur

Cannot use mouse or keyboard to read the text after Trial2. Input box just displays text till Trial 2 and then cannot scroll further. This happens after putting `blur()` property.
I want the user to be able to read the full text, as well keep the blur property as it is doing some validations.

```
<input type="text" id="mybox" value="This is trial1 This is trial2 This is trial3" onfocus="this.blur()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my question ! @Rancho thanks for the idea!

```
$("#txtUSLead").on("mouseover", function () {
if ((this.value.length) > 25)
{
$('#txtUSLead').css('width', ((this.value.length + 1) * 7) + 'px');
}       
});
$("#txtUSLead").on("mouseout", function () { $('#txtUSLead').css('width', 180); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have both things.

Maybe try a readonly attribute instead of the onblur or better explain why you think you need blur()

Comment: or just make your input wider if this works for your scenario.

Comment: This post must be add as a comment

Comment: Increasing the size is an issue, as it is happening thru some bootstrap css which I am not sure about at this point !

Answer (score 0):

Partly taken from [Resize input to fit its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663716/resize-input-to-fit-its-content).

```
document.getElementById('mybox').onmouseover=function(){
   this.size = ( this.value.length > 10 ) ? this.value.length : 10;}


    document.getElementById('mybox').onmouseout=function(){this.size = '10'}
```

Comment: Thanks @rancho ! your solution works great for normal code, but not in my application, the input box remains as is, I just discovered by app has some size framing done thru bootstrap, so I will have to thorough check how the sizes are getting rendered..